# is it against google analytic's terms of service to send data to google to identify visitors?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy

i'm using google event tracking on our website, and would like to send the email address used in our newsletter subscription form in the event tracking call so I can see what events visitors have completed on our site.

Is this allowed by google's terms of service? I remember reading somewhere that this is not allowed, but can't find the reference anymore.

If it is against google's TOS, should I store some unique key for the email address on our server instead and then send this key in the event tracker?

thanks!

Comment: Read their TOS.  If you still don't know, talk to a lawyer or ask Google.  Nobody is going to give legal advice online without an established attorney-client relationship.

Comment: @cdhowie:  Plenty of people give legal advice online without an established attorney-client relationship.  The fact that they do this indicates that they aren't qualified to do this, and aren't taking any responsibility, and generally should be disregarded.  Just being pedantic here.

Comment: @David: Under the law there is a difference between "legal advice" and "opinion."  If you claim to give legal advice (or, sometimes, don't clarify that what you give is not legal advice!) you become liable for damages that may result from that advice.

Comment: i am not asking for any hard legal advice here. i'm just a developer dude trying to get a general idea about what is allowed and what is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely restricted by [their terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html). You cannot store any personally identifiable information. Even storing a unique key is generally seen as violating this rule.

> ```
> 7. PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use
> ```
>
> the Service to track or collect
>   personally identifiable information of
>   Internet users, nor will You (or will
>   You allow any third party to)
>   associate any data gathered from Your
>   website(s) (or such third parties'
>   website(s)) with any personally
>   identifying information from any
>   source as part of Your use (or such
>   third parties' use) of the Service.
>   You will have and abide by an
>   appropriate privacy policy and will
>   comply with all applicable laws
>   relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your
>   websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide
>   notice of your use of a cookie that
>   collects anonymous traffic data.

This isn't legal advice, but, on its face, what you're describing is not allowed. What that means for you is between you and your lawyers.